# How to create a folder inside of the SampleScene folder unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I wanna sort my objects in unity, it looks like a total mess right now. This question sounds really stupid but I really can't get it working. I also can't find anything on the internet. Does anyone know how to create a folder inside of the SampleScene folder inside of Unity to sort my objects?

Comment: **In hierarchy view:** Create an empty gameobject to serve as a folder. Drag and drop gameobjects to make them children.
**In project view:** Right click and click create folder. Drag and drop objects to make them children.

Comment: Are you actually talking about a folder? -> simply do right click -> create -> folder or create it in your systems filebrowser ..

Answer (score 1):

Just right click in the empty space and Create -> Folder.

[image: Image showing how to create folder]

Answer (score 0):

Just use empty GameObjects as folders, because it seems you can't create any folders in Hierarchy view